# How to encrypt VM box via VBoxManage?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, encryption, vagrant, disk-encryption

I've created VM box via [`Vagrantfile`](https://gist.github.com/gabrielelana/9189eab5df963deba30f), however when I'm trying to encrypt the storage, I've got the following error:

```
$ VBoxManage encryptmedium aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee --newpassword - --newpasswordid my_username --cipher "AES-XTS256-PLAIN64"
Enter new password:
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage: error: Encrypt hard disk operation for this cipher is not implemented yet!
```

The same happening when not specifying any cipher.

Why this doesn't work? And how do I encrypt the VM in a proper way?

---

Additional info:

```
$ VBoxManage --version
5.0.14r105127

$ VBoxManage showvminfo secure | grep 'SATA.*UUID'
SATAController (0, 0): ~/VirtualBox VMs/secure/box-disk1.vmdk (UUID: aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee)
```

I'm on OS X (El Capitan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support *Disk Encryption* of the virtual machine, you've to install *Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack*. Please install the Extension Pack from the [VirtualBox download site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

It's not included by default, because it can contain system level software that could be potentially harmful to your system.

Please note that the version of *Extension Pack* needs to match with your existing *VirtualBox* version, so in case of installation issues, you need to upgrade your *VirtualBox* platform package (shutting down all VM machines is required).

After installation, the encrypt operation can be executed using command-line interface, using following syntax:

```
VBoxManage encryptmedium "uuid|filename" --newpassword "file|-" --cipher "cipher id" --newpasswordid "id"
```

See: [VirtualBox 5.0 Enhancements and Features: Disk Image Encryption](https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/entry/virtualbox_5_new_enhancement_and)

> Note: The “Disk Image Encryption” is shipped as a VirtualBox extension pack, which must be installed separately.

Comment: What a weird place to bury that info, it wasn't even mentioned in the Download link (or the VBoxManage manual section). And a terrible error message by VBoxManage

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a VirtualBox bug... is there a way to list all the supported ciphers?

Or maybe the order of options matters, [some oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/entry/virtualbox_5_new_enhancement_and) and the [VBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) show this order:

```
VBoxManage encryptmedium "uuid|filename" --newpassword "file|-" --cipher "cipher id" --newpasswordid "id"
```

Or try using the GUI, should be here:

[image]